# Is there a better way to see data change posted on index.html webserver (NGINX) besides refreshing the page every second?

Tags: c++, flutter, nginx, push-notification, webserver

I have made a flutter app which gives notifications whenever I get an error on the machine running embedded. The way I achieved this is by posting the error on the hosted webserver's page every time I have an error, and then the moment the error is resolved, removing it from the page. Meanwhile, the flutter app connects to this webserver page via the ip address using http request and then refreshes it every second to see if there is any data. If there is, then it sends a notfication on the phone, and starts comparing the data every second to see if any change happens. If the data is changed, another notification is sent else it keeps on refreshing the page and reading it.

The program I used to write the error to this webserver is through C++ code which opens the index.html file, performs write operation and then closes the file every time a new error occurs. The moment, the error is resolved, the file is again opened and the record is deleted making the index.html blank and ready to receive another error.

I want to know if there is any better way to achieve this so that the page only refreshes on new data arrival. As I have been told, refreshing the webpage every second can cause extra pressure on the embedded processor it has been hosted on. Any leads will be appreciated.

Thanks for your time ^^.

Comment: You could use a WebSocket or Server-sent events. What you're currently doing is called short polling. Even long polling reduces network traffic.

Comment: see https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/web-sockets

Comment: So looking at the suggestions, both short and long polling does not seem like a viable choice. I would try websockets and update the results here. Thanks!